# Postfix/Dovecot multiple authentication backends

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I trying to configure multiple sources on a postfix/dove server of all these:

```
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/valiases.cf,ldap:/etc/postfix/useraliases.cf,ldap:/etc/postfix/groupaliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps= ldap:/etc/postfix/mailbox.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = ldap:/etc/postfix/vdomains.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/login.cf
```

So for example I would extend virtual_alias_maps with:

```
virtual_alias_maps = virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/valiases2.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/valiases.cf
```

How can I tell postfix that even if the 2nd ldap authentication fails (for example the server is completely down) then ignore it?

I have the mysql auth working but if I add the secondary ldap source and the ldap server is not configured I will always end up with:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <test@domain.com>: Temporary lookup failure;
```

Comment: Well that's the a feature from postfix that prevents   *legitimate email* permanently  rejected when your DBs is down

Comment: You wanted to say, when <b>a</b> db is down. This has to work if the second ldap source is not available. Is there a way to disable this kind of checking in postfix?